# Como obtengo el CIDR osea el prefijo de la máscara, de mi PC en Java

Tags: java, java-8

Hola buenas noches deseo saber se puede lograr obtener el CIDR de mi computadora, es decir si la mascara de mi PC es 255.255.255.192 el CIDR sería /26 por que son 26 bits encendidos, pero quiero obtenerlo automáticamente en un programa en Java, quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de hacerlo, mi profesor me dijo que con network interface podría lograrlo, pero investigue la documentación de Java y no existe nada similar que haga tal cosa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que son cosas distintas

1. En tu sistema operativo obtienes el dato de tu IP, mascara y brodcast address

En UNIX/Linux

```
host:~ host$ ifconfig en1
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 68:a8:6d:58:81:0b 
    inet6 fe80::6aa8:6dff:fe58:810b%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5 
    inet 10.0.1.12 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.0.1.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autosele
```

La mascara (netmask), te dice cual es tu CIDR, ver (para este caso que esta en hex): http://www.pawprint.net/designresources/netmask-converter.php

Con esto ya sabes que tu CIDR es 10.0.1.0/24

2. Ahora sabiendo esto, haces una class que obtenga estos datos desde tu OS y haga la equivalencia.

Saludos!

Comment: Mira esto, con JAVA directo: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html

Comment: bueno gracias si lei eso en la documentación, incluso prové esos métodos y otros que no están allí para ver que devolvían, voy a tratar de buscar una solución por mi cuenta, si logro encontrar la solución lo compartiré...